# Edit Aptio Ami bios

Tags: bios

My laptop vendor turned off the fields after the first  "Save and Exit", and added his own, with cuted settings.
     You can see that the fields are duplicated.

pic. 1 shows which fields work and which ones do not.
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfy49.png

pic. 2 shows what is in the unnamed parent "folder"
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/AkZ8b.png

pic. 3 shows what is in the Mine folder (and it shows and works!)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/7s4hY.png

In pic 4, it is written that it is in the Advanced (do not confuse with AdvanceHuuance) folder and this is NOT displayed in the BIOS.
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/2gUV8.png

All the unintelligible names like wtfmfg and AdvanceHyuans, as well as USER instead of default, I added. This is the only thing I can edit - the field name and accessibility.

I can not turn off the Advanced, Chipset, Here, Security and Save and Exit or add new ones. Well, or I do not know how. The right mouse button is not click anywhere. Double-click to edit the name only. Clicking on "Handle" does not cause anything.

```
 The BIOS model - PEGATRON CORPORATION A35 1.0
```

My soft for edit - AMIBCP v.4.53
I saw the checkboxes in version 3.27 near these "folders", but 3.27 does not open my files.

How do I get a normal configuration, but not those that set my vendor?

i tried paste image, but SO always think what it is code and i cant post.

Comment: Sorry, post editing. SO think shat image links is code.

Comment: Am I the only one here finding it difficult to understand what is the issue?

Comment: @Thangadurai 
Added screenshots.

Comment: This community is about programming questions. Not about fixing somehow broken computers!

Comment: @GhostCat sorry!
It's not really a computer fix, it's a change in the bios values. I saw a lot of questions with the tag "bios" and not only where there was definitely no programming. I apologize if i asked in the wrong place and ask me to redirect me to the right stackexcange section.

Answer (score 0):

AMI BCP cannot remove or add new setup page as you said.
You will need get the code and build the bios as you need.
Before that, you need have a AMI bios training, I assume you're not a BIOS engineer.